# PHP CURL Request Failed with 503 Error

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I have implemented CURL script to execute API call.But it gets failed with 503 Error.Where in it works in REST Client in browser.

[CODE](http://pastebin.com/CFnDML3F)

[LIVE LINK FOR RESPONSE](http://iosappsonline.com/tempo2.php)

Thank You In Advance,
MarkSys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);` ? that should be actually `TRUE`.

Also, since you are doing a request to a HTTPs URL , You need to add this param too `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`